# create variable name based on text in the sentence

Tags: python, automation, summarization

I have a list of sentences. Each sentence has to be converted to a json. There is a unique 'name' for each sentence that is also specified in that json. The problem is that the number of sentences is large so it's monotonous to manually give a name. The name should be similar to the meaning of the sentence e.g., if the sentence is "do you like cake?" then the name should be like "likeCake". I want to automate the process of creation of name for each sentence. I googled text summarization but the results were not for sentence summarization but paragraph summarization. How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of task is used for natural language processing. You can get a result similar to what you want by removing [Stop Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words). Bases on this [article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/clean-text-machine-learning-python/), you can use the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) for dealing with the stop words. After installing the libray (`pip install nltk`), you can do something around the lines of:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

# load data
file = open('yourFileWithSentences.txt', 'rt')
lines = file.readlines() 
file.close()
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for line in Lines: 
    # split into words
    tokens = word_tokenize(line)
    # remove punctuation from each word
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    # filter out stop words

    words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
    print(f"Var name is {''.join(words)}")
```

Note that you can extend the `stop_words` set by adding any other words you might want to remove.